# webxml attribute is required with Servlet 3.0

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, vaadin, vaadin7

I get this error when trying to compile a Vaadin WAR:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project testvaadin-web: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
```

I know this error means that maven cannot find my web.xml, but in the "Book of Vaadin" it says that **web.xml is not needed** when using Servlet API 3.0 and the Annotation `@WebServlet` in your UI class.

I am compiling my widgetsets in a separate profile (according to [this](http://bluegulf.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/tutorial-of-setting-up-eclipsemavenvaadinjetty-project-ide-2/) guide) and it compiles fine when I rnu this profile. However, when I compile only the web-project, I get above mentioned error.

What gives?

Do I override the maven behaviour somehow? Vaadin didn't even create a WEB-INF directory. I guess I could create WEB-INF folder and keep a "ghost" web.xml in there to keep maven happy, but that doesn't seem right.

Am I missing something?

Does anyone know a good solution to this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

By default maven-war-plugin will fail if it can't find web.xml, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml). If you are creating Maven project using latest archetype, you will get this parameter set to false:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

If you want to use web.xml instead of annotations, just create WEB-INF/web.xml and define servlet there, see Book of Vaadin for detailed instruction.

Comment: I just found it. =) I actually had failOnMissingWebXml in the widget compilation. Thanks

Comment: I needed to add the <version>2.4</version> to the plugin to get rid of all my warnings.

Comment: Note that you can do this a little more succinctly just by adding `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` to your `<properties>` section

Comment: just included code snippet in web.xml from the above code snippet as suggested by @Sergey Makarov, it solved the problem. Thanks a lot. Saved 20 minutes there.    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Answer (score 3):

I landed here with a similar error but using Eclise Luna (4.4) with Maven 3.0

I ended up doing this:

1. move the **WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml** to **src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml**
2. Use the `<webXml>` to specify the location of web.xml

> ```
> <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>3.0</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>       <!-- we dont want the version to be part of the generated war file name -->
>       <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
>   </build>
> ```

3. Run **mvn package** and see a BUILD SUCCESS (for WAR)

Before this I tried using the original path of the **web.xml** file

```
<webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
```

But maven did not pickit up and is best to follow the maven folder structure

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I guess this solution may be really nice if you actually do need to use web.xml in some other part of the same project.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.0.0 the [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) works out of the box with no `web.xml`.

Up to at least Maven version 3.3.9 the packaging `war` [binds to a older version of the `maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging), so you need to explicitly set the version in your `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Earlier versions of the `maven-war-plugin` had the parameter [`failOnMissingWebXml`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) set to `true` by default, what causes your problem. See [Sergey Makarovs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186921/1347968) on how to manually set the parameter to `false` if you need to use a older version of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are not following the standard maven directory layout as described here [Maven directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)